# Oracle Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help setting up a many-to-many relationship.

I read through articles, and it looks like I need to use an intersection table that contains the IDs from the two main tables to create a sort of 1-many mapping.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

List of Employees and basic information
[EMPLOYEE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF15r.png)

List of Projects and where the project site is located
[PROJECT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y3gg.png)

The link table between projects and the employees
[LINK TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0scQV.png)

I created the LINK table and input the data. Based on this, Bob Brown is assigned only to Project A while David Doe is assigned to Project A and C. Looking the other way, Project A has three employees assigned - Bob Brown, David Doe, and Sam Smith.

It works fine until I try to find information on Janet Jones. Since she doesn't have a project assignment, there is no entry in the LINK table and I cannot add one with a (null) PROJ_ID, what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean:

> how do I enter a person without a project into the link table?

You do not, they are not involved in a project so there is nothing to link to so they do not need an entry in the link table.

Rows 5 and 6 in your link table should not be in the link table as there is no link when one side of the relationship is `NULL`. Just omit them and use `OUTER JOIN`s or `NOT EXISTS` to find those employees/projects.

For example, if you want to look for employees where there is no entry in the link table then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employee e
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   link l
         WHERE  l.emp_id = e.emp_id
       );
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employee e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN link l
       ON l.emp_id = e.emp_id
WHERE  l.emp_id IS NULL;
```

If you want all the details then use `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT e.*, p.*
FROM   link l
       FULL OUTER JOIN employee e
       ON l.emp_id = e.emp_id
       FULL OUTER JOIN project p
       ON l.proj_id = p.proj_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_pyXCiMY)

Answer (score 0):

In short, nothing!  It's working as expected.  Since Janet does not have a project, she would not be in the associative table until she is assigned a project.

Also, your associative table does not need it's own primary key.  The primary key is the composite key that is formed from the primary keys from the employee and project tables when an entry is added.

Comment: The link table certainly needs to have its primary key, for otherwise you may have Bob associated to Project A N times, which would be a waste of storage and make no sense repeating the same thing N times.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu The primary composite key would stop that already, as it's already a primary key.